# how to see changes of voteCount with StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a StreamProvider of list of Product an firestore data

```
 StreamProvider<List<Product>>.value(
        value: DatabaseService().products,
      ),
```

Now i have a details page for this list of Products
if i click the list for details page i give one object to the  details page

```
DetailsPage(courseData: product)
```

I need to make a upvote button in this details page for it to change in firestore data also

```
  if (voted) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('products')
            .doc('${widget.courseData.id}')
            .update({"voteCount": widget.courseData.voteCount - 1});
      } else {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('products')
            .doc('${widget.courseData.id}')
            .update({"voteCount": widget.courseData.voteCount + 1});
      }
      isVoted = !isVoted;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
```

Here the courseData doesnt change if it clicked upvote button as its value is not fromthe streamProvider but from the

> DetailsPage(courseData: product)

How should i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the new value, which you don't know, I'd recommend using the `increment()` operation to accomplish the same.

```
if (voted) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .doc('${widget.courseData.id}')
        .update({"voteCount": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) });
} else {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .doc('${widget.courseData.id}')
        .update({"voteCount": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
    }
    isVoted = !isVoted;
} catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

In addition to not needing to know the current value (which I think is your problem), it also works better in both offline and multi-user scenarios.

Comment: the widget.coursedata.id  value wont be updated in realtime because it got value from the parent just one object so i woul like it to change also

Comment: now i can change the data but the problem is to show that changing realtime but as i got the data as object from the class. i doesnt change i have come out of the page and reclick the card to updated page.